# method of class receiving unknown arguments

Tags: python, class, methods

I have a class that I defined, the class currently takes 2 arguments, self and savepath. A method of this class takes 2 arguments, self. Within that method, I call a function which again takes 2 arguments, local_hash and filename, however, upon calling this the method, I get the error described below. I assume it has something to with the self argument but I can't figure out where or why. And for the record, put_nowait() is a method of a default module. I wouldn't assume I'd need to post the code for all of the relevant default modules I'm using.

## The method:

```
def cache_files(self, path):
    self.folder_path = path
    self.md5_queue = Queue.Queue()
    accepted_file_types = ['.jpg', '.png', '.gif']
    self.hash_directory = os.walk(self.folder_path, topdown=True)
    if self.folder_path != None:
            for root, subfolders, images in self.hash_directory:
                for filename in images:
                    try:
                        if filename[-4:] in accepted_file_types:
                            self.local_hash = hash_sum(os.path.join(root, filename))
                            self.md5_queue.put_nowait(filename, self.local_hash)
                    except IOError:
                        continue
    print 'Directory has finished caching, exiting...'
    return self.md5_queue
```

---

## The def run():

```
def run(self):
    # references pickle file if available
    md5_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'md5.pickle')
    try:
        self.md5_dict = md5_unpickler(md5_path)
    except IOError:
        pass
    if self.hash == True:
        self.cache_files(self.savepath)
    else:
        self.build_queue()
```

---

## The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Cirno\Dropbox\CirnoCrawler\crawler.py", line 98, in run
    self.cache_files(self.savepath)
  File "C:\Users\Cirno\Dropbox\CirnoCrawler\crawler.py", line 84, in cache_files

    self.md5_queue.put_nowait(filename, self.local_hash)
TypeError: put_nowait() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Comment: what the `def put_nowait()` in class?

Comment: `put_nowait()` is a method of the Queue module.

Comment: Found my answer. put_nowait() is expecting 2 arguments, `put_nowait(self, (tuple,here))`. not `put_nowait(tuple, here)`

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing 'self' in the argument list of the 'put_nowait' method. Something like this I believie:

```
class md5_queue:
    def put_nowait(filename, local_hash):
     .
     .
     .
```

Changing it to the following should fix your problem:

```
class md5_queue:
    def put_nowait(self, filename, local_hash):
     .
     .
     .
```

Comment: how is that insufficient information? :s put_nowait is a method of Queue, which is a default module..

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer. put_nowait() is expecting 2 arguments, put_nowait(self, (tuple,here)). not (tuple, here).